# Using Winsock and C to talk with an FTP server

Tags: winsock

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1):

[TCP/IP Sockets in C: Practical Guide for Programmers](http://cs.baylor.edu/~donahoo/practical/CSockets/winsock.html) has a number of C code examples using Winsock.

There isn't one for FTP but it will get you on your way.

Answer (score 0):

Although you can use Winsock you'll be better off if you use a higher level API, such as [WinINet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383630.aspx), which already implements the [FTP protocol](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384180.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Read the [FTP RFC](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc959/).